# What is the name of this array operation?

Tags: arrays

We all know that naming things is one computer science's 2 hardest problems. Here's something for which I'm trying to find the name, if it already has one.

Let's say I have an array comprised of 2 or more equal-length arrays. This array has 4 arrays of 3 items each:

```
[
    [1,     2,     3],
    ['a',   'b',   'c'],
    ['i',   'ii',  'iii'],
    ['one', 'two', 'three']
]
```

and I want to apply some function to get this resulting array of 3 arrays of 4 items each:

```
[
    [1, 'a', 'i',   'one'],
    [2, 'b', 'ii',  'two'],
    [3, 'c', 'iii', 'three']
]
```

Look at the original input and imagine you're taking vertical slices across the child arrays.

Is there a language out there that can do this with a built-in function, and if so, what is the function called? Or, in general, is there a good, succinct name for this operation?

Comment: A matrix calls it transpose. Not sure whether this can be called a matrix though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called **transpose** and is a well known operation on matrices in mathematics, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose.